# Nodejs promises - compose a pipeline from async functions in sequence with support for early exit

Tags: node.js, promise, pipeline

Recently I was playing with async function composition in nodejs and realized it would be nice if I could wrap them into pipeline in order to reuse them elsewhere. Each output from previous async function would be input for the next one. For the basic implementation I've used code like this:

`pipeline.js`

```
function run(tasks, input) {
  let context = input;

  const reducer = (acc, task) => acc.then((result) => {
    context = result;
    return task(context);
  };

  return tasks.reduce(reducer, Promise.resolve(context));
}
```

`tasks.js`

```
/* do nothing, return input */
const task1 = async (context) => {
  console.log(`previous output: ${context}`);
  return context;
}

/* do nothing, return input */
const task2 = async (context) => {
  console.log(`previous output: ${context}`);
  return context;
}

...
```

`test.js`

```
/* import tasks -> tas1, task2, ... */
const tasks = require('tasks.js');
const pipeline = require('pipeline.js');

pipeline.run(tasks, null)
  .then((output) => console.log('done')
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

where :

- `pipeline.js` : pipeline implementation
- `tasks.js` : function definitions from which I can compose pipeline
- `test.js` : code to test everything

This is the basic scenario that will suit my needs most of the time. However, I've came to conclusion that I will most likely need early exit (early pipeline finalization, that is) when certain condition is met. I couldn't find a way to cleanly achieve this and the only thing that worked for me was rejecting promise with some error which will act as a circuit breaker. This is approach I used:

`pipeline.js`

```
function run(tasks, input) {
  let context = input;

  /* added cancel closure */
  const cancel = () => {
    throw new PipelineCancelError();
  }

  const reducer = (acc, task) => acc.then((result) => {
    context = result;
    return task(context);
  };

  return tasks.reduce(reducer, Promise.resolve(context));
}
```

so my tasks would receive additional function as argument so I can cancel some pipeline stage :

`tasks.js`

```
/* do nothing, return input */
const task3 = async (context, cancel) => {
  console.log(`previous output: ${context}`);
  if (someCondition) {
    /* cancel pipeline */
    cancel();
  }
  return context;
}
```

My question is: is there some clean approach to achieve early exit and completing pipeline when some condition is met without throwing an error?

Also, I've found this project which looks promising (`express` style handlers), but I have difficulties handling errors when task throws unhandled error : [promise-pipeline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-pipeline)

Note that I'm NOT an experienced nodejs developer.

Thanks!

Comment: i would advise against `promise-pipeline`. to me, it looks like they conflate continuation-passing style with promises. and it is 6 years old with 1 weekly download, which is probably from users of the package's only dependent, `package-json-to-template`.

Comment: This seems easier with async/await

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to pass `cancel` to your `task` -

```js
function run(tasks, input) {
  let context = input;

  /* added cancel closure */
  const cancel = () => {
    throw new PipelineCancelError();
  }

  const reducer = (acc, task) => acc.then((result) => {
    context = result;
    return task(context); // <- pass cancel to task
  };

  return tasks.reduce(reducer, Promise.resolve(context));
}
```

Let's see how we might fix this. We will add a simple `sleep` for demonstration purposes -

```js
function run(tasks, input) {
  const cancel = e => { throw e }
  const reducer = (acc, task) => acc.then(result => task(result, cancel))
  return tasks.reduce(reducer, Promise.resolve(input))
}

function sleep (ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

async function task1 (context, cancel) {
  await sleep(1000)
  console.log(`previous output: ${context}`)
  return context.toUpperCase()
}

async function task2 (context, cancel) {
  await sleep(1000)
  console.log(`previous output: ${context}`)
  return context + "!"
}

async function task3 (context, cancel) {
  await sleep(1000)
  console.log(`previous output: ${context}`)
  cancel(Error("task3 cancelled"))
  return context + "?"
}

run([task1, task2, task2], "hello").then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
previous output: hello
previous output: HELLO
previous output: HELLO!
HELLO!!
```

And here's a demonstration of the `cancel` effect -

```js
function run(tasks, input) {
  const cancel = e => { throw e }
  const reducer = (acc, task) => acc.then(result => task(result, cancel))
  return tasks.reduce(reducer, Promise.resolve(input))
}

function sleep (ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

async function task1 (context, cancel) {
  await sleep(1000)
  console.log(`previous output: ${context}`)
  return context.toUpperCase()
}

async function task2 (context, cancel) {
  await sleep(1000)
  console.log(`previous output: ${context}`)
  return context + "!"
}

async function task3 (context, cancel) {
  await sleep(1000)
  console.log(`previous output: ${context}`)
  cancel(Error("task3 cancelled"))
  return context + "?"
}

run([task1, task2, task3, task2], "hello").then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
previous output: hello
previous output: HELLO
previous output: HELLO!
Error: "task3 cancelled"
```

You can respond to the cancellation by using the second argument to `.then` -

```js
run([task1, task2, task3, task2], "hello")
  .then(console.log, console.error) // <-
```

Or you can use `.catch` -

```js
run([task1, task2, task3, task2], "hello")
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error) // <-
```

Comment: Ah, yes, totally forgot `cancel` there. Thanks for extensive answer anyway but I was wondering if there is a way to achieve chain-breaking without throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved using cancellable promises from my lib ([c-promise2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-promise2)). See the [Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-goldberg-7mzob?file=/src/index.js)

```
import { CPromise } from "c-promise2";

function run(tasks, input) {
  return tasks.reduce((acc, task) => acc.then(task), CPromise.resolve(input));
}

const task1 = async (context) => {
  console.log(`[task 1] previous output: ${context}`);
  await CPromise.delay(1000);
  return "data1";
};

const task2 = async (context) => {
  console.log(`[task 2] previous output: ${context}`);
  await CPromise.delay(1000);
  return "data2";
};

// Complex deeply cancellable task to show the benefits
const task3 = function* (context) {
  try {
    console.log(`[task 3] previous output: ${context}`);
    yield CPromise.delay(1000);
    console.log("[task 3] Downloading data...");
    yield CPromise.delay(1000);
    console.log("[task 3] Analyzing...");
    yield CPromise.delay(1000);
    console.log("[task 3] Uploading data...");
    return "data3";
  } finally {
    yield CPromise.delay(1000);
    console.log("[task 3] Deleting temporary data...");
  }
};

const ts = Date.now();

const promise = run([task1, task2, task3], "input-data")
  .then((output) => console.log(`Done: ${output}`))
  .catch((err) => console.error(`Failed after[${Date.now() - ts}ms]: ${err}`));

setTimeout(() => promise.cancel(), 3500); // cancel the pipeline (promise)
```

Comment: I could give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can use the node stream api. There is methods to stop/resume/pipe/whatever the stream.

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help answering my question as I don't intend using streams at all throughout my pipeline. Thanks anyway.